# mongo cluster collection count showing different every time

Tags: mongodb, cluster-computing, configserver

**I had a replica set earlier**
 **which i have converted to cluster now**

current configuration is

3 shard
   4 router
   4 config server

Now when i trying to get count of one of collection sometime it is showing null and some time some value , why this is happening?
please help

Comment: This question really belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](https://dba.stackexchange.com) which is the site to use for database administration and configuration questions. StackOverflow is for programming topics only, of which this question is not. Please move your question to the correct site by deleting and reposting. Also include more information or your question will be closed there as well.

Comment: What version of Mongodb are you using?

Comment: 3.4.2 and 3.4.6